# PyautoGui 3.6 import Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have install PyautoGui without any errors on my Windows 7 machine. When I am importing pyautogui, it is giving me "ImportError: No module named 'pyautogui'" error. I am using Python 3.6.0a1 shell.

I am a new bee at python, so  your help will be much appreciated.

I have other versions of python before which I uninstalled and then reinstalled 3.6. Their folders are still in C drive. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using virtual environments in windows in order to avoid having issues where you may have not installed a given package for a specific version of python?

Comment: no, I have not. Can you please guide me to any link to resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you use `pip install pyautogui` or `pip3 install pyautogui` to install PyAutoGUI? Are you sure you ran the pip/pip3 program for the version of Python you are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Tim Reilly's blog](http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/setup-a-virtualenv-for-python-3-on-windows/). 
You have a couple of environments which means you may not have `pyautogui` installed in Python 3.6.

Virtual environments mitigate this because you can run multiple versions of Python with different packages installed. Once you have an environment setup,

```
mkvirtualenv environmentName
workon environmentName
```

you can install a given package and ensure that you have a relatively standardized setup.

Alternatively, use something like `pip install` to make sure you have installed (or reinstall) this in your current python environment.